# Internationalization of Chinese Yuan, and Chinese exports?

Tags: international-trade, exchange-rates

If Chinese Yuan is internationalised and more countries use it to settle payments, then wouldn't that cause strengthening of Chinese Yuan and make Chinese exports uncompetetive ?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, all things equal, yes ! However, China (and many emerging markets as well) accumulate foreign exchange reserves in order to keep the value of their currency relatively low compared to their 'natural rate', thus keeping a high competitivity for chinese exporters.